# Can somebody recogize the stye and/or meaning of the characters in the Image? (Characters identified: 壽)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

This is the metal cover of the scabbard of a sword I bought in Chinatown Los Angeles.

[image: Picture of the metal cover of the scabbard]

Comment: These are [seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_script)-aesthetic characters inspired from 百壽圖 (*Chart of 100 [ways of writing] "Longevity"*). You can Google image search 百壽圖.